# Count the number of unique records of a column for combination of two columns?

Tags: sql-server

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/caa9f/4

I have a table Employee with three columns(EmpID,DateID,SourceID). There can be duplicate records in the table. I need to add one more row, say SourceCount to count the no of unique sources for unique combination of DateID and EmployeeID. The table should remain entact but new column should be added which shows how many unique sources are there for each combination of dateid and empid. Example of first row : (1,2,4,1), second row:(1,2,4,1), forth row (3,2,7,2) etc

This is what I have tried.

```
select EmpID,
       DateID,
       SourceID,
       Rank() over ( partition by DateID, EmpID,SOurceID order by SourceID ) SourceCount     
 from Employee
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` and `COUNT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee e
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT
    SourceCount = COUNT(DISTINCT SourceID)
  FROM Employee e2
  WHERE
    e2.EmpID = e.EmpID
    AND e2.DateID = e.DateID
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a simple count distinct query:

```
select distinct EmpID, DateID,
count(distinct  SourceID)
from Employee
group by EmpID,DateID
```

Comment: Group by changes the number of rows from source

Comment: Yes I thought that was what was requested as it makes more sense. But I re-read the question and see that all original rows are required. Don't know why you would want that, but you are right.